# Java-8: How to sort Map (based on values) using Map.Entry#comparingByValue while ignoring case sensitivity?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, case-insensitive

I want to sort a Map based on values alphabetically and ignoring case sensitivity and return the list of Keys.

```
 /**
   * This method will sort allCostPlanDetailsRows based on Value in <Key,Value> pair
   *
   * @param sortingOrder_ whether to sort the LinkedHashMap in Ascending order or Descending order
   * @return List<String> returns List of costPlanDetailsRowId in sorted order
   */
  private List<String> sortCostPlanDetailRows( SortingOrder sortingOrder_ )
  {
    return _allCostPlanDetailRows
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .sorted( sortingOrder_ == SortingOrder.DESC ? Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByValue(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).reversed() : Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.nullsFirst(
          Comparator.naturalOrder())) )
      .map( Map.Entry::getKey )
      .collect( Collectors.toList() );
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

**Note:** Suggestions are welcomed on if I can improve above piece of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `naturalOrder` comparator, you can use [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER):

```
return _allCostPlanDetailRows
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .sorted( sortingOrder_ == SortingOrder.DESC ? Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByValue(Comparator.nullsFirst(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)).reversed() : Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.nullsFirst(
          String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)) )
      .map( Map.Entry::getKey )
      .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Comment: thanks just one doubt, Will that be applicable for only Null values or for all other values as well?

Comment: You will have the `null`s first, as you're using `Comparator.nullsFirst`. All the strings that aren't `null`s will then be sorted regardless of their case.